# Symfony 1.4 - redirect to homepage

Tags: symfony-1.4

All pages in my application is secured by default, except the home page and login page. In my settings.yml I set

```
login_module:           homepage
login_action:           index
```

So if I access a secured page it redirects to homapage.

The content of all my pages are loaded via ajax. So after several hours when I came back to my account and click on menu the content loaded the home page. So I got 2 menus, 2 footers. I need to redirect to homepage.

Answer (score 0):

After long time User's session expired so it's redirecting your ajax request to login page. So, You may change handling of login action. In case of that you can check referrer url as below in your login action.

```
$link = $request->getReferer();
// if $link match with your AJAX link, you should send some custom message or flag in response of AJAX request.
// so you can identify that user's session expired.

// On failure detection of AJAX request, you can redirect browser to login page.
```

**Edit**

if you have multiple Ajax request. you can do as following.

```
// under executeLogin()
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
{
    echo '0'; 
    exit;
}
```

At AJAX handler side you can do like below

```
function ajaxResponseHandler(response)
{
       if(response == 0)
       {
          window.location = <?php echo url_for("@login"); ?>
       }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english. hope this helps you. Let me know if it works :-)